# How to test if command is alias, function or binary?

Tags: shell, alias, function

I have command `foo`, how can I know if it's binary, a function or alias?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're on Bash (or another Bourne-like shell), you can use `type`.

```
type command
```

will tell you whether `command` is a shell built-in, alias (and if so, aliased to what), function (and if so it will list the function body) or stored in a file (and if so, the path to the file).

Note that you can have nested cases, such as an alias to a function. If so, to find the actual type, you need to unalias first:

```
unalias command; type command
```

For more information on a "binary" file, you can do

```
file "$(type -P command)" 2>/dev/null
```

This will return nothing if `command` is an alias, function or shell built-in but returns more information if it's a script or a compiled binary.

**References**

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Answer (score 7):

In zsh you can check the `aliases`, `functions`, and `commands` arrays.

```
(( ${+aliases[foo]} )) && print 'foo is an alias'
(( ${+functions[foo]} )) && print 'foo is a function'
(( ${+commands[foo]} )) && print 'foo is an external command'
```

There's also `builtins`, for builtins commands.

```
(( ${+builtins[foo]} )) && print 'foo is a builtin command'
```

EDIT: Check [the zsh/parameter module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module) documentation for the complete list of arrays available.

Comment: This is very helpful. I am new to zsh. Where can I find some documentation on this feature of zsh. I've skimmed through the documentation printed from the command `run-help aliases`.

Comment: @tkolleh, just added a link to the corresponding zsh documentation.

Answer (score 5):

The answer will depends on which shell you're using.

For zsh, shell builtin `whence -w` will tell you exactly what you want

e.g.

```
$ whence -w whence
whence : builtin
$ whence -w man     
man : command
```